# full_profile sample json required

Tags: linkedin-api

We've integrated `Sign In with LinkedIn` with our development and returning `basic_profile` data.

We'll probably need `full_profile` data so it looks like we'll need to apply to become a LinkedIn Partner.

However, it would be useful to test first using sample `full_profile` data, in JSON format. Depending on the result, it may not be worthwhile applying to become a LinkedIn Partner.

Is it possible to acquire such sample data? Just a single user profile would suffice, preferably complete, obviously containing either false or redacted data.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the JSON by hand, adding the full profile fields to the JSON you already have. The full profile fields is detailed [in linkedin docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/full-profile). According to their documentation, full-profile fields add to those of the basic profile.

Alternatively you can try to generate one based off of your own profile using [this linkedIn to json tool](https://github.com/JMPerez/linkedin-to-json-resume).

Hope it helps.